# How do you apply values to a Y axis in GGplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data frame that I have created from raw data so as to add the percentage before brining into ggplot

```
    AR      name    Percentage
1   16-19   252     0.4%
2   20-24   2850    4.4%
3   25-29   6476    10.0%
4   30-34   5882    9.1%
5   35-39   7128    11.0%
6   40-44   6347    9.8%
7   45-49   8178    12.6%
8   50-54   10862   16.8%
9   55-59   10417   16.1%
10  60+     6376    9.8%
```

I am trying to have the AR on the x-axis then the bars showing the percentage, it should be a relatively simple thing to do but I just can't seem to get it to work

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to extract the numeric value from what presumably is a character string (with the "%" symbol):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_table("
AR      name    Percentage
16-19   252     0.4%
20-24   2850    4.4%
25-29   6476    10.0%
30-34   5882    9.1%
35-39   7128    11.0%
40-44   6347    9.8%
45-49   8178    12.6%
50-54   10862   16.8%
55-59   10417   16.1%
60+     6376    9.8%"
)

df |> 
  mutate(p = as.double(str_extract(Percentage, ".*(?=%)"))) |> 
  ggplot(aes(AR, p)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous("Percentage", labels = scales::label_percent(scale = 1))
```

[image]
You can get `ggplot` to do the proportion calculation for you. This might look complicated but essentially says:

- `group` all the rows together
- sum all the `name` values
- calculate the `prop` of the total each represents
- label these as percentages

```r
df |> 
  ggplot(aes(AR)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = after_stat(prop), weight = name, group = 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous("Percentage", labels = scales::label_percent(scale = 100))
```

[image]

Comment: For this use case, `geom_col(aes(y = name / sum(name)))` would probably be simpler.

Comment: Very true! I just like using a little `after_stat` wherever I can :D

Comment: Haha. Me too. And after I managed `stage` I use it everywhere. :D